# Firefox __doPostBack not working after idle time

Tags: asp.net, firefox, dopostback

Got really strange Firefox issue. Using the Microsoft __doPostBack javascript function in web forms page. Used for tab control, we have got each tab click calling the __doPostBack function.

Works ok on my dev machine with all browsers but got a colleague who has an issue if he leaves the page idle for circa 3 -4 minutes. After this delay if he selects a new tab which calls the __doPostBack function the call to theForm.submit(); just hangs and get requested timeout.

No .net calls are seen in Firebug.

The __doPostBack event is called just theForm.submit() function just doesn't execute.

If he does not have this idle time works ok.

It is also ok for him on all other browsers.

Confused any ideas??

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of the problem **AVG Link Scanner**!

Disabled Link Scanner and now everything working OK.

Problem only manifested itself on local host.

Answer (score 1):

What add-ons does this person have installed?  There are many that modify the way javascript works.  Use a clean install of Firefox to test this.  I suspect it's a non-issue, since it works fine for you.

Comment: We have a builds and test environment and it works ok for colleague there too so think you are right.
Strange though.